# Multipeer Connectivity: Invalid service type

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I am trying to use the Multipeer Connectivity framework but I am getting a crash while trying to instantiate `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` with a `serviceType` called "stc-classroom-vik".

Here is the code:

```
private func setUpSession() {
    self.session = MCSession(peer: self.peerId);
    self.session!.delegate = self;
    
    self.browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: self.peerId, serviceType: "stc-classroom-vik");
    self.browser!.delegate =  self;
    
    self.advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: self.peerId, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "stc-classroom-vik");
    self.advertiser!.delegate = self;
}
```

and this is the crash/error I am getting:

```
2014-08-15 12:24:42.689 Xavier[614:254319] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid serviceType passed to MCNearbyServiceBrowser'
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe you're only allowed to have one hyphen in your `serviceType` parameter string, and it needs to be 15 characters or fewer. Yours has two hyphens and 17 characters.

From the comments for `MCNearbyServiceBrowser()`:

> The serviceType parameter is a short text string used to describe the 
>    app's networking protocol.  It should be in the same format as a 
>    Bonjour service type: up to 15 characters long and valid characters 
>    include ASCII lowercase letters, numbers, and the hyphen.  A short name
>    that distinguishes itself from unrelated services is recommended; for 
>    example, a text chat app made by ABC company could use the service type
>    "abc-txtchat".

Answer (score 2):

Your service type length is more than 15 characters long and containing 2 hyphens.

I suggest you write a small function to check for serviceType string format for safety.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct in that a Bonjour service type may only have 15 characters.

However, there is not a "one hyphen" limit. The wording of the Bonjour specification is to describe the characters which are permitted in the serviceType.

"stc-class-vik" is a valid serviceType